# How to get panoramas from ALAsset objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

We have about 2k objects, which are instance of class ALAsset, and we need to know, which files are panoramic images.
We have tried to get CGImageRef from ALAsset instance and check width/height ratio.

```
ALAsset *alasset = ...
CFImageRef = alasset.thumbnail; // return square thumbnail and not suitable for me
CFImageRef = alasset.aspectRationThumbnail; //return aspect ration thumbnail, but very slowly
```

It isn't  suitable for us, because it works slowly for many files.

Also we have tried to get metadata from defaultRepresentation and check image EXIF, but it works slowly to.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [alasset defaultRepresentation] metadata]; //very slowly to
```

Is there any way to make it better?

Thanks

Comment: can you expand on "This ways are not suitable for me", so people understand the problem. Is it just the performance issue which you mention in the comments (if so, it might be worth adding it to the main question text so people do not miss it).

Comment: @VladMihaylenko how did you manage to detect panoramic images in an ALAsset?

Comment: @NicolasManzini I answered to my question below.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly, I've found this solution for ALAsset:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = ...;
NSOperation *queue = [NSoperationQueue alloc] init];
static NSString * const kAssetQueueName = ...;
static NSUInteger const kAssetConcurrentOperationCount = ...; //I use 5 
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = kAssetConcurrentOperationCount;
queue.name = kAssetQueueName;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    /*You must check the group is not nil */
    if (!group)
      return;
    /*Then you need to select group where you will search panoramas: for iPhone-Simulator it's @"Saved Photos" and "Camera Roll" for  iPhone. It's actuality only for iOS 7 or early. */
    static NSString * const kAssetGroupName = ...;
    if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] kAssetGroupName]) {
      [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if (!asset)
          return;
        [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
         //I use @autoreleasepool for instant memory release, after I find panoramas asset url
          @autoreleasepool {
            ALAssetRepresentation *defaultRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation;
            if ([defaultRepresentation.UTI isEqualToString:@"public.jpeg"]) {
              NSDictionary *metadata = defaultRepresentation.metadata;
              if (!metadata) 
                return;
              if (metadata[@"PixelWidth"] && metadata[@"PixelHeight"]) {
                NSInteger pixelWidth = [metadata[@"PixelWidth"] integerValue];
                NSInteger pixelHeight = [metadata[@"PixelHeight"] integerValue];
                static NSUInteger const kSidesRelationshipConstant = ...; //I use 2
                static NSUInteger const kMinimalPanoramaHeight = ...; //I use 600

                if (pixelHeight >= kMinimalPanoramaHeight && pixelWidth/pixelHeight >= kSidesRelationshipConstant) {/*So, that is panorama.*/}
             }

        }];

      }];
    }
  } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
      //Some failing action, you know.
  }];
};
```

That is. So, I think that is not the best solution. However, for today I have not found any better.

Comment: I was going to try to access metadata embedded in the jpg. Your post seems like a faire solution to me. thanks a lot you saved me some time!

Comment: ALAssetRepresentation has a dimension property. it wasn't enough for the purpose?

Comment: @NicolasManzini Getting of defaultRepresentation is a "bottle neck" for this issue.  After you get it, you don't need to worry about a time for another operation like getting metadata or etc.